# unable to create xslt for a specific requirement

Tags: xslt

New to xslt. Here is the input xml.

```
<Response>
     <RecordNumber/>
     <id>2014-12-24</id>
     <person>            
        <gender>MALE</gender>
        <genericLocations>            
           <effective>2012-11-28</effective>
        </genericLocations>
        <genericLocations>              
           <expiration>2012-11-27</expiration>               
           <effective>2008-12-09</effective>
        </genericLocations>
        <genericLocations>
            <expiration>2008-12-08</expiration>               
           <effective>2006-01-13</effective>
        </genericLocations>
        <genericLocations>
           <expiration>2006-01-12</expiration>               
           <effective>2001-07-17</effective>
        </genericLocations>
        <genericLocations>              
           <expiration>2001-07-16</expiration>               
           <effective>1901-01-01</effective>
        </genericLocations>
      </person>
  </Response>
```

Here is the required output XML :

```
<Response>
     <RecordNumber/>
     <id>2014-12-24</id>
     <person>            
        <gender>MALE</gender>
        <genericLocations>            
           <effective>2012-11-28</effective>
        </genericLocations>            
      </person>
  </Response>
```

The output xml need to contain only one "genericLocations" node in which the "expiration" is either empty (or missing) or "expiration" is in the future (greater than today's date.)

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342805/xslt-1-0-compare-dates

Comment: **1.** Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. If XSLT 1.0, which specific processor? **2.** What if there are are more than one nodes that meet the criteria? What if there are none?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming XSLT 2.0, you want

```
<xsl:template match="person">
  <xsl:copy-of select="gender, 
     genericLocations[not(xs:date(expiration) le current-date())][1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

plus an identity template to copy everything else unchanged.