# display current date data in xslt from xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML

```html
<Entity>
    <EntityTypeContent>
      <EntityTypeId>8074</EntityTypeId>
        <Content>
          <Xml>
            <IdValuePairs>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>Name</Id>
                <Value>Seminar1</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarDate</Id>
                <Value>07/08/2017</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarDateSortable</Id>
                <Value>20170705</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarStartTime</Id>
                <Value>6:00 PM</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarStartTimeSortable</Id>
                <Value>180000</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              </IdValuePairs>
          </Xml>
        </Content>
    </EntityTypeContent>
    <EntityTypeContent>
      <EntityTypeId>8075</EntityTypeId>
        <Content>
          <Xml>
            <IdValuePairs>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>Name</Id>
                <Value>Seminar1</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarDate</Id>
                <Value>07/09/2017</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarDateSortable</Id>
                <Value>20170705</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarStartTime</Id>
                <Value>6:00 PM</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarStartTimeSortable</Id>
                <Value>180000</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              </IdValuePairs>
          </Xml>
        </Content>
    </EntityTypeContent>
    <EntityTypeContent>
      <EntityTypeId>8076</EntityTypeId>
        <Content>
          <Xml>
            <IdValuePairs>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>Name</Id>
                <Value>Seminar1</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarDate</Id>
                <Value>07/09/2017</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarDateSortable</Id>
                <Value>20170705</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarStartTime</Id>
                <Value>6:00 PM</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              <IdValuePair>
                <Id>SeminarStartTimeSortable</Id>
                <Value>180000</Value>
              </IdValuePair>
              </IdValuePairs>
          </Xml>
        </Content>
    </EntityTypeContent>
</Entity>
```

and I have an XSLT code to generate HTML using the above XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <section id="page-attend-event">
            <div>
                <h2>Upcoming Seminars</h2>
                <xsl:for-each select="/Entity/EntityTypeContent">
                    <xsl:sort select="EntityTypeId/Content/Xml/IdValuePairs/IdValuePair[Id='SeminarDateSortable']/Value" data-type="number" />
                    <xsl:sort select="EntityTypeId/Content/Xml/IdValuePairs/IdValuePair[Id='SeminarStartTimeSortable']/Value" data-type="number" />
                    <div>
                        <h1>
                            <xsl:value-of select="EntityTypeId" />
                        </h1>
                        <div>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Content/Xml/IdValuePairs/IdValuePair[Id='SeminarDate']/Value" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this code is generating the HTML with all the XML data.

But I want to display the XML data where its element Seminar Date is greater than current date

the issue is I am using XSLT 1.0 but here how can I add the condition with the current date. I have tried to get the current date, but in XSLT 1.0 we don't this function

Please help

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627949/how-to-find-the-current-date-in-xslt-1-0/26628225#26628225

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342805/xslt-1-0-compare-dates